# Nautilus and nemo wont display directories in Home directory since new update for 16.04 for Spectre, Meltdown vulnerability

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates, nautilus, nemo

Ever since the new kernel update to fix intel's cpu Spectre, Meltdown vulnerability Nautilus and nemo wont display directories in the Home drive. 
I can't even do a `ls` from the terminal it just sits there.

```
55@ftg:~$ uname -a
Linux sys76 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


55@ftg:~$  lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

GNOME nautilus 3.14.3
nemo 2.8.6
```

I even turned off several options in Nautilus ...see image below  And several programs take about 30 seconds to open instead of 2 seconds like shutter, gedit etcc..

[image]

Comment: Hello, how did you manage to upgrade Kernel / Ubuntu ? from your screenshot I can see that you're on 16.04.2 which goes with 4.8 kernel version... HWE for Ubuntu 16.04.4 goes with the 4.13 kernel version... Did you do any partial upgrades?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack as you can see the Release of 4.13 kernel for Ubuntu 16.04 is scheduled to be released in February.

Comment: @JoKeR Your guess is as good as mine... I know there where some issues with the updates I didn't think this was one of them...how can I fix this?  but they did have some bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742323
And
http://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-vs-meltdown-ubuntu-gets-second-update-after-first-one-fails-to-boot/

Comment: Probably Ubuntu team will implement this fix to the 4.10 kernel too but as of now I can say you're running on experimental features because kernel version 4.13 has not been released yet for your distro.

Comment: @JoKeR  Thanks  I installed Kernel 4.8.xx using `Ukuu` and it's working http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JoKeR I installed Kernel 4.8.xx using `Ukuu` and it's working normally again here's a link in-case someone runs into something similar. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu